# How to close an open web socket from java script, html 5

Tags: php, websocket

I have a simple chat program than runs on a php web-socket. There is simple php script that runs on server computer which processes incoming data and forwards it to other sockets.

The questions is how can I check if a a websocket is closed from clients end.

I know that when socket.close(); is called on client side, php script receives 2 bytes of data but when I unmask it, it seems to be empty.

Please can anyone shed little light on this. Thank You

UPADTE:
This is weird. 
There is certain data when I unmask I get ♥8. why is this ?

UPDATE 2:

Okay,

Further investigation reveals the following

if socket.close(); is called from your browser. Your socket_recv() function will recieve 6 bytes of data and when unmasked it will have null.

If you browser windows is closed which has websocket active your socket_recv() function will get 8 bytes of data and when unmasked will reveal ASCII characters 3 and 233.

I dont exactly know whats hap

Comment: Read this article, should give you some insight. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive more information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeat_(computing)

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-36